# How to set gxmessage to run at login, and make exit codes trigger events

Tags: login, startup

I wanted to set a 'computer terms of use' message to pop up at login. If the user clicked 'Agree' they could continue to use the machine; if they clicked 'Cancel' it would reboot the machine. Here's what I had:

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is to set terms of use for this computer and force logged in guest to accept terms.
# If done correctly, it will restart the computer in the event that the terms are not accepted.

gmessage "This is a public terminal. Any use must be suitable for eyes of all ages. Failure to comply will result in your immediate removal from the property without any refund or discount." -center -title "Terms of Use" -default "Accept" -center -buttons "Accept":0,"Decline":1>/dev/null

case $? in
0)
gmessage "Enjoy our public terminal. :)" -center -title "Thank you for accepting the Terms of Use." -buttons "I will!":0;;

1)
(sudo reboot);;

esac
```

Can anyone help me fix this? It was working as designed until I put it in the Startup Applications list. I have done `chown root.root /path/to/script` and also `chmod u+x /path/to/script`. I also edited visudo to include the line `%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script` and still nothing. The script runs fine, pops up all my windows fine, <strike>but won't reboot the computer when someone declines the terms of use</strike> and logs the user off if they don't accept the terms. I'm no longer stuck, <strike>and my boss is breathing down my neck to implement this fix</strike> the fix has been implemented (had someone attempt to print some graphic adult materials from our public computer terminal, which got stuck in the printer buffer; a little girl tried to print some coloring book pages later, and we barely managed to intercept the adult materials before they were seen by a non-adult).

Fully functional code follows.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is to set terms of use for this computer and force logged in guest to accept terms.
# If done correctly, this script will log the user out in the event that the terms are not accepted.

gmessage -fg red -bg black "   This is a public terminal. Any use must be suitable for eyes of all ages. Failure to comply will result in your immediate removal from the property without any refund or discount." -center -title "Terms of Use" -default "Accept" -center -buttons "Accept":0,"Decline":1>/dev/null

case $? in
0)
gmessage "   Enjoy our public terminal. :)" -center -title "Thank you!" -buttons "I will!":2;;

1)
(killall -u super8guest);;

esac


case $? in

2)
gmessage "Click here when you are finished." -center -title "Cleanup" -buttons "Done":3;;

esac

case $? in

3)
(killall -u super8guest);;

esac
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I came up with all by myself, after hours and hours of research. Posted here in the hopes that it will help others who find themselves in a similar situation.

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script is to set terms of use for this computer and force logged in guest to accept terms.
# If done correctly, this script will log the user out in the event that the terms are not accepted.

gmessage -fg red -bg black "   This is a public terminal. Any use must be suitable for eyes of all ages. Failure to comply will result in your immediate removal from the property without any refund or discount." -center -title "Terms of Use" -default "Accept" -center -buttons "Accept":0,"Decline":1>/dev/null

case $? in
0)
gmessage "   Enjoy our public terminal. :)" -center -title "Thank you!" -buttons "I will!":2;;

1)
(killall -u super8guest);;

esac


case $? in

2)
gmessage "Click here when you are finished." -center -title "Cleanup" -buttons "Done":3;;

esac

case $? in

3)
(killall -u super8guest);;

esac
```

If anyone has ideas on how to pretty up the code, or ways to make it work better, please don't hesitate to share. I'm still learning.